# Did Netanyahu say "We will turn Gaza into a deserted island" in early October 2023?

Tags: quotes, israel, israel-hamas-war, benjamin-netanyahu

According to [a October 7, 2023 Al-Jazeera article](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/10/7/world-is-watching-fears-grow-of-a-massive-gaza-invasion-by-israel), Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu said:

> “We will take mighty vengeance for this black day,” the Israeli leader said in a televised address. “We will take revenge for all the young people who lost their lives. We will target all of Hamas’s positions. We will turn Gaza into a deserted island. To the citizens of Gaza, I say. You must leave now. We will target each and every corner of the strip.”

But a lot (in fact, all that I've looked at) of the Western coverage of this "mighty vengeance" speech (e.g. [NBC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wquCRPxaHdU)) omitted the part about a "deserted island", only Al-Jazeera and some really obscure websites have that [extended] quote on Google. CNN perhaps [comes](https://edition.cnn.com/middleeast/live-news/al-aqsa-storm-militants-infiltrate-israel-after-gaza-rockets-10-07-intl-hnk/h_442bd00f97f8bb6e8469efe7a9683ed0) the closest to having the rest of the speech as Al-Jazeera, but the part about the "deserted island" is missing there too:

> "What happened today has never been seen in Israel. We will take mighty vengeance for this black day," Netanyahu said in a televised speech from Israel's Government Press Office, which was carried by Reuters.
>
> "Israel will reach every place Hamas is hiding," Netanyahu said, referring to the militant group behind the attacks. "I tell Gaza's people to leave those places now."

So, did Netanyahu say that "deserted island" bit? (I don't understand Hebrew myself.)

Comment: Related: [Who is the Israeli official that said that Gaza would be reduced to “a city of tents”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/81699/8320).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, he did not.
The [full speech in Hebrew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsv7RNKX-BA&ab_channel=IsraeliPM) is available at the Israel PM YouTube channel. As it is in Hebrew, some inaccuracies with translations are possible and I couldn't find an official translation. The full transcript of the relevant sections are:

> צה"ל יפעיל מייד את כל עוצמתו כדי להשמיד את יכולות חמאס. נכה בהם עד חורמה וננקום בעוצמה על היום השחור זה שהם עוללו למדינת ישראל ואזרחיה. "כפי שאמר ביאליק: "נקמת דם ילד קטן עוד לא ברא השטן.
>
> את כל המקומות שהחמאס נערך בהם, של עיר הרשע הזאת, כל המקומות שהחמאס מסתתר בהם, פועל מתוכם, נהפוך אותם לעיי חורבות. אני אומר לתושבי עזה, צאו משם עכשיו כי אנחנו נפעל בכל מקום ובכל העוצמה.

Which is translated to English as (translated by me, not a professional translator):

> The IDF will immediately apply its full force to destroy Hamas's abilities. We will strike them until they are extirpated and exact mighty vengeance for this black day which they have visited upon the state of Israel and its citizens. As Bialik had said: "Vengeance of blood of a small child - the devil has not yet created".
>
> All the places where Hamas is formed at, of this evil city, all the places where Hamas is hiding, acting from, we will turn them into rubble. I'm telling the people of Gaza, get out of there now, because we will act everywhere in full force.

The translation of the first part about "mighty vengeance" is a correct translation (and this is why I used it as well even if this is perhaps not the phrase I would have used).

But then it adds things that were never said. Netanyahu doesn't say that Gaza will be attacked in general, but talks specifically about the places where Hamas is located in and uses.

Comment: I slightly tweaked SIMEL's translation (nothing of significance).

Comment: As a native Hebrew speaker and an Israeli, this transcript and translation are accurate. Upvoted.

Comment: So probably what you have translated as "rubble" has been translated by Al Jazeera as "a deserted island?"

Comment: It would be useful to take the last sentence apart a bit more in detail, because that seems to be where the translation of Al-Jazeera has either missed the meaning you consider correct, or took some liberty in interpreting it. How clear does the original state what's meant by "get out of **there** now"? It does seem a bit ambiguous whether he's saying the people should get away from the Hamas hideouts, or get out of Gaza completely.

Comment: But the article says "**Fears of a huge ground invasion of Gaza are growing after Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu promised to turn the besieged Palestinian enclave into a “deserted island” in response to the worst attack his country has suffered in decades**". I think your answer is deceiving and misleading. Even your translation says "we will turn them into rubble". The essence of the Al-Jazeera article is correct, but you're making it look like it is not.

Comment: @user1271772, ...when "them" is described as _places Hamas is hiding_. That's a critical distinction (in choices as to communication, if not in actual tactics). The question specifies Gaza _as a whole_, whereas the speech refers to militarized locations _within_ Gaza.

Comment: @YosefBaskin which word are you saying is *island*?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy then why are those "hiding places" being called a "city"?

Comment: @user1271772, I'd want someone who knows the source language; as an English speaker I might be reading a nuance that isn't there in the original, but when I read "places of this [..] city", it's not the city as a whole but specific places within it that are the referant. If the word "of" weren't there it would be a different meaning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy since Hamas is the governing authority of Gaza (since 2007), "places where Hamas is formed" can be interpreted as all of Gaza. It's unlikely that Netanyahu wants to flatten the entire Gaza land in which more than 2 million people live, but he **did** indicate an intention to flatten parts of Gaza where Hamas is (which can be interpreted as the whole of Gaza or significant amounts of it at least). This answer is making it look like he said nothing at all. "No he did not" is a misleading opening sentence. A better one would be "Yes, but how much of Gaza is open to interpretation"

Comment: Aljazeera translated it incorrectly. The PM used the biblical ׳עיי חורבות׳ which means rubble/a pile of stone. This is different from the word ׳איי׳ which means islands of... Stick a biblical phrase into an automated translator and that's what you get.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, you are wrong, עי is not an island, אי is an island, עי, means a pile, but I don't think that it's used in isolation only as עיי חורבות, meaning as a pile of rubble, as opposed to חורבה which is just a single ruin. Neither the word Island, nor any form of the word Isolation are used here.

Comment: @user1271772, the mention of the "evil city" is forwarded by a direct reference to the gathering places of Hamas and followed by the hiding and operational places of Hamas. If frames the subject as Hamas related places pretty unambiguously. I'm going into speculation here, but that translation is not even the result of a sloppy or bad translation, but a deliberate mistranslation and misrepresentation of the speech.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, you can read about עי here: https://hebrew-academy.org.il/keyword/%D7%A2%D6%B4%D7%99/

Comment: @SIMEL you're throwing our the word "misinformation" in multiple places, but the worst misinformation is your very own. The answer is clearly "Yes" and you're going to great lengths to find ways to interpret the words in such a way to make people think the answer is "No".  Your own translation says: "**I'm telling the people of Gaza, get out of there now, because we will act everywhere in full force**." Rather than starting your answer with "No he did not", a more correct answer would start with "Yes he did, but the 'literal translation' is open to interpretation".

Comment: @user1271772, misinformation was used with regards to the translation of the word עי as an island, which is simply not true. Your quote is missing the context of the first part. And no, if we accept your interpretation (which is, again, meaningless as the people of Gaza have nowhere to go to) then the answer would be "He didn't say it, but some people interpret it that way". And as OP couldn't find any other source other than Al-Jazeera that interpreted it that way shows that this is not a widely accepted interpretation.

Comment: Why are you getting so stuck up on the word "island"? Can we agree at least, that Gaza is not an island? So what if my quote didn't contain the first part? There's a limit for the size of comments and we all know what the first part says. I also don't see why you're getting so stuck up on whether or not what Netanyahu told the people of Gaza to do, is easy for them to do. The fact is that **your** very own translation says "**I'm telling the people of Gaza, get out of there now**". Are you trying to say that this was just a joke, because it's not actually easy for people to leave Gaza?

Comment: The OP never said that he "couldn't find any other source", he said that "Western media" left out a part that was included by Al-Jazeera. Have you noticed though, that Western countries are pro-Israel and anti-Palestine? Fizz, sorry if I got your pronoun wrong!

Comment: @user1271772, The island point was not directed at you, I don't know what's your deal with it. Someone claimed that עי is an island, and it's not. Just as someone who translates English would claim that a ship is a fluffy grass eating animal.

Comment: @user1271772 Context matter. Here are two examples: "The building on 21, 2nd street, the people of Gaza, get out of there now". Vs. "The Gaza strip. The people of Gaza, get out of there now". So see, the first directs them to get out of a specific place, the second directs to leave the entire strip, all end with "The people of Gaza, get out of there now", the meaning is different. You, as a non Hebrew speaker are welcome to write your own answer and find other credible western, eastern or southern sources that translate it the same way as Al-Jazeera.

Comment: @SIMEL "**I'm telling the people of Gaza, get out of there now**" is very clear. Your attempt to change its meaning in your last comment hasn't convinced me of anything. It's also offensive that you're assuming that I don't speak Hebrew.

Comment: @user1271772, again you leave out the previous part and context, even in a short comment where length is not an issue. You are welcome to provide your own answer. If you think that my translation is not good enough or with another credible source agreeing with your point of view. Complaining that western media is biased and then arguing that only the Al-Jazeera interpretation is true is הגמל לא רואה את דבשתו (בעברית במיוחד בשבילך שלא תעלב או תעלבי לי).

Comment: I don't think you need to say it in that way (the Hebrew part), but I was planning to write an answer of my own. I've been working on something else at the moment.

Comment: If you're sure of your translation of "All the places where Hamas is formed at, of this evil city", then AJ translation is a fair guess at the meaning of a contradictory tautology. Since all of Gaza is one city, if Israel targets the "evil city", it's targeting all of Gaza, but in the same sentence says will only target places where Hamas is. In context, given how pissed off he is, the former is more likely.

Comment: It's analogous how Ahmadinejad's (in)famous quote that "This occupation regime over Jerusalem must vanish from the arena of time.”, got translated as "Israel must be wiped off the map", because of what was known about him in context, whereas the strict translation was just calling for regime change.

Comment: @Eugene, Gaza is not one city, The Gaza strip is an area of land containing Gaza city and other cities, villages and towns. Which Al-Jazeera know and thus translate to "every corner of the strip". So the most generous interpretation would be in this case that they overstated the scope of expected destruction. But, he doesn't end with "this evil city" and puts a suffix directing at Hamas, he encapsulates the city with direct references to Hamas aligned places.

Comment: @Eugene, This is extra context that I didn't put in the answer because this is my personal interpretation. As an Israeli, many times when talking about militants in Gaza the "underground city" or "tunnel city" mentioned as the fighting infrastructure that Hamas built under the Gaza strip, consisting of bunkers, connecting tunnels, underground rocket launchers and even fighting tunnels that are dug into Israeli territory (which were also used in this attack) and more. So when I hear there "Evil city" I think of the Terror infrastructure build there, not the actual city where people live.

Comment: @SIMEL so you're saying that in context, the "evil city" commonly refers to the Gaza underground. Do you have a link to an article with that usage? Google translate seems pretty good for Hebrew these days. As to Gaza being a city, from looking at the satellite view, the whole strip is significantly denser than my city, Seattle. I see it's split into several municipalities, but so is here(the actual Seattle part is ~15% of what non locals think of as "Seattle"). Is it common to refer to Gaza city as specifically the municipality of Gaza?

Comment: @Eugene Gaza City is just one part of the Gaza strip but when they say "[there is no safe place in Gaza](https://youtu.be/xhqC_PFhP_Y?si=mp60H78sQ1A4ISWA)", and when they say "the might of Israel's arsenal thundered down on Gaza's **cities**",  they're talking about the whole strip, not just Gaza city.

Comment: @user1271772 I was responding to the phrase "THE evil city". That's why I asked him if he was sure the phrase is correctly translated. Does Hebrew have a definite article?(he thinks that refers to the tunnels) City is a loose term, the guys you posted may use the correct term cities, others may not. By US standards, all of Gaza is one (very dense) city. If my home got bombed, it would be in the news as a Seattle suburb, even though it's technically a separate city.

Comment: @RoyFalk: thanks for the explanation. BTW, Google auto-translates  ׳עיי חורבות׳ as "ruined villages". אי׳ חורבות׳ as "island of ruins".

Comment: @Eugene, Yes, the Gaza strip is densely populated, but it's still not one city, it's not even one continuous urban area, you can see clearly on Google maps and satellite photos that there are agricultural areas south of Gaza city and then between Rapah and Khan Yunis. The names Beit Lahia and Beit Hanun are also famous here, as they are the northern most at the strip and so are the main (but not exclusive) lunch places of rockets into Israeli cities. If someone says "Gaza city" they don't mean the Entire strip, if they would say just 'Gaza', then they probably mean the entire strip.

Comment: @Eugene, Hebrew has a definite article, and it's used in the phrase. 'This evil city', can be translate as 'this city of evil' as well. But, no one address the Gaza strip as a city. Gaza city is precise to the city itself, and Gaza strip is precise for the entire strip, just Gaza can be used for both. I can't say what "evil city" refers to exactly, I just said my interpretation. I can say that I don't know of previous times that that phrase was used. But, I can say for sure putting clear references to Hamas affiliation before and after puts it in the context of only Hamas related sites/areas.

Answer (score 14):

To add to [@SIMEL's excellent answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56102/22266), the specific mistranslation here is related to the phrase used by Netanyahu at the [1:37 mark of his speech](https://www.youtube.com/live/Dsv7RNKX-BA?si=g-qskTAmdpEzd-eM&t=97). Netanyahu says (transliterated into latin script for the benefit of readers who can't read Hebrew):

> [...] nahafoch otam le-eeyay horavot

In English, this translates as:

> [...] we will turn them into rubble.

The expression "eeyay horavot" is a Hebrew expression meaning "rubble". The word "eeyay" can also be understood to mean "islands". However, it's important to emphasize that in Hebrew "eeyay" (the first word in the two-word compound expression that means "rubble") and "eeyay" (with the meaning of "islands") are *two completely different words*, which are spelled differently in Hebrew but are pronounced the same. (That is, they are [homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone).)

What might have happened here is that the translator could have been someone who is not a native Hebrew speaker, and they were preparing their translation based on the *audio* of the speech rather than a written transcript. In that case, on hearing the word "eeyay" they might have reasonably decided that it should be translated as "islands". Then hearing the following word "horavot" they decided that the correct translation for this expression was "deserted island".

However, only someone with a rather poor knowledge of Hebrew (or an AI translation software) would make such a mistake, since as any native Hebrew speaker knows, the expression "eeyay horavot" is a standard compound expression in Hebrew that can only ever appear with the other "eeyay" that doesn't mean "islands".

To summarize, the "deserted island" part is definitely incorrect, but there is a plausible explanation for how a translator might arrive at it not through intentional misrepresentation but by making a good faith mistake.

In addition, there are other inaccuracies in the translation that are harder to attribute to the translator's imperfect command of Hebrew. Netanyahu very clearly is not saying that Israel will turn *all of Gaza* into rubble, but only the parts of Gaza from which Hamas operates. And he quite clearly cautions the people of Gaza to get away from *those specific parts of Gaza*, not to "leave" (implying to leave Gaza) as the Al-Jazeera translation suggests.